# Symfony form collection read-only for first entry

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

How can I set the read-only option only for the first item in the collection when rendering a form?

My simple models:

```
class Main
{
    public $others;
}

class Other
{
    public $field1;

    public $field2;
}
```

Simple Form Type for my models:

```
class MainType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('others', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new OtherType(),
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'App\MyBundle\Entity\Main',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'maintype';
    }
}

class OtherType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('field1')
            ->add('field2')
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'App\MyBundle\Entity\Other',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'othertype';
    }
}
```

And simple action method my controller

```
//...
public function indexAction($id)
{
    $main = new Main();

            $other1 = new Other();
    $other1->field1 = 'a';
    $other1->field2 = 'b';
    $main->others[] = $other;

            $other2 = new Other();
    $other2->field1 = 'c';
    $other2->field1 = 'd';
    $main->others[] = $other;

    $form = $this->createForm(new MainType(), $main);

    //...isValid, persist, flush...
}
//...
```

I can make a condition when manually render the form, but I want to know if possible at the form code to enter such a restriction.

Answer (score 2):

Currently it is not possible to have the rows of a collection have different options. I invite you to create a feature request on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues) if you feel that this would be a valuable addition.

Comment: +1 Just curious @Bernhard. Is this also the case with Entity field type? If one wishes to set read only for the first entry of an entity field type, would that be possible?

Comment: That depends on whether you render the field as drop down, checkboxes or radio buttons?